# Did I go to the "fair" or the "faire"?

Tags: orthography

Which one's correct? I've seen both claiming to be correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair.

'Faire' would is an old-fashioned spelling and would be somewhat pretentious nowadays. You also sometimes see 'fayre' in the context of food, normally something like 'We serve traditional home-cooked fayre'.

Comment: Huh... "Faire" makes me think of French ("to do" or "to make"), so I always went with Fair but thought it might be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: "Fayre" is just another spelling of "fair". The word meaning food is "fare"; I've never seen "fayre" used with this meaning.

Comment: "Fayre" is an alternative spelling of "fair", but I'm not sure about it being an alternative of "fare" (as in your example). See: http://is.gd/V1wM2R

Comment: Ah well, if you've never seen 'fayre' in that context then it can't be right, right? http://www.caterham-independent.co.uk/eating-out/86-traditional-home-cooked-fayre-at-the-harrow-september-2009   http://www.dalgarven.co.uk/news.htm  It's very common in the UK.

Comment: Why is it pretentious? Some seem to use the old fashioned spelling to add a touch of class to event banners/advertising. It doesn't really impress me as more or less classy----but it sounds ironically pretensions to accuse them of pretentiousness.

Comment: It is pretentious because it pretends to an antiquity (such spellings disappeared in the first half of the 17th century) which it does not possess.

Answer (score 4):

**Fair** is the standard word in modern English, and is usually what’s appropriate.

*Faire* and *fayre* are older spellings, used in specific names but not widely used as generic terms today.  So a fair might call itself *The Cottesloe Village Faire* to evoke historical associations; but except when referring to it by name, it would still usually be called a *fair*.  (Just as one would write “Jayne’s Ye Olde Gifte Shoppe is a very nice shop.”)

There are a few exceptions: *faire* and *fayre* get used as generic terms within some historical re-enactment subcultures—most notably, for [Renaissance faires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_faire).  If someone writes “I’m going to a faire next weekend”, I would assume they mean something like that.

Answer (score 2):

`"Fair"` is the common, modern usage. `"Faire"` is the old-fashioned (pretentious) spelling, but it's not out of usage.

Thus one goes to is going to a modern event, it might be the state `fair`, and if one it attending something more old-fashioned, it might be a renaissance `faire`.